# Inbound Email Attachments

Tags: visualforce, email

I have a requirement where in i need to store the attachments in the emails received to notes&attachments section in salesforce for a particular object record automatically.Is that possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are few steps which could help:

- Enable Email Service in Salesforce by navigating `Setup > Develop > Email Service`. More details [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_inbound_what_is.htm)
- You need to create a class which implements `Messaging.InboundEmailHandler` Interface. And define Interface method -
  `handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope)`

Ex:

```
public class EmailProcess implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler 
{
  // email contains subject, CC, body and attachment, envolope contants To & From address
  public Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.Inboundenvelope envelope) 
  {
    List<Attachment> attList = new List<Attachment>();
    // This will extract all blob attachments from email
    // For text type attachment Messaging.Inboundemail.TextAttachment can be used
    for (Messaging.Inboundemail.BinaryAttachment file : email.binaryAttachments) 
    {
      Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
      attachment.Name = file .fileName;
      attachment.Body = file .body;
      // some hardcoded or id extracted from email reference
      attachment.ParentId = parentId;
      attList .add(attachment);
   }
   if(attList .size()>0)
   {
     insert attList;
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a shared Interface for `BinaryAttachment` and `TextAttachment` that would let someone write shared code for both of them, or do you have to explicitly repeat the logic for both?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from Developerforce Cookbook

http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/retrieving-email-attachments-and-associating-them-with-records